# Develop SAML Integration with Okta in our java web application

Tags: java, tomcat, saml, okta

We are totally new to SAML and Okta. We are a Java based SAAS web application which will be used by multiple customers. We are looking forward to implement SAML integration with Okta and we need the details to get started with.

How do we register ourselves as third party application in Okta ? if so, can we support multiple customers IdPs with single SP.

How do we develop SAML integration in Java and integrate that with Okta.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Vasantha,
as you probably know, your app will act as a SAML Service Provider, so you just generate SAML SP meta data and hand it over to Okta admins. It actually does not matter which SAML IdP implementation the 'SSO partner' is using. SAMLv2 as an 'internets body' standard is product agnostic.
You can support multiple IdPs, but most SAML SP libs may not support this out of the box.
You should not try to implement a SAML SP yourself. It's way more than just handling SAML messages. You may choose one of various SAML Java SP implementations.